# JPA: how to detect if existing entity was updated?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there a better way to check/detect if entity was updated in db? The reason being is the system publishes any changes to an external webservice, we dont want to publish if there is no changes as the webservice is slow to respond (we want to keep the soap body light as we are posting variable text lenght).

My current approach is described below:

For a given entity:

```
public class Comment {
   int id;
   String text;
}
```

In my service class I will detect it like so:

```
public class CommentServiceImpl {
   void saveList(List<Comment> comments) {
      for(Comment c : comments) {
         Comment existing = this.findById(c.id);
         if (existing != null) {
            boolean nochange = existing.getText().equals(c.getText());
            if (nochange) { 
               //do nothing, we don't want to publish to external webservice
            } else {
               this.save(c);
               externalWs.publish(c);
            }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How about a last updated column in the database? This could be automatically updated by the database, or by the application, it's your choice. Then just let the webservice return all entries updated since some timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer in JPA but, if u are using Oracle, DCN is a pretty good api. Check it:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm